# Postgres won't start after blackout

Tags: windows-10, postgresql

My Postgres service was running when a blackout happened and now it won't start anymore.

After starting the computer again, I noticed that the service was not up and running, so I tried to manually start it (but it fails).

Here's the log:

```
2017-12-22 16:11:45 BRST LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2017-12-22 13:30:09 BRST
2017-12-22 16:11:46 BRST FATAL:  the database system is starting up [ad nauseam]
```

After trying to start the service manually, `postmaster.pid` is created, so next time that I try to start the service, it will complain about that file:

```
2017-12-22 16:18:04 BRST FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
2017-12-22 16:18:04 BRST HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 8900) running in data directory "C:/MyFolder/Base"?
```

If I delete that file (after checking if there's no `postgres.exe` process active) and try to start it again, it will complain about not being able to connect to TCP/IP ports, etc.

What can I do to fix my Postgres service?

Btw: Postgres version 9.4 on Windows 10 15063.729

Comment: Have you checked the various Windows event logs (`%windir%\system32\eventvwr.msc /s`)?

Comment: Yes, the logs went to the event viewer, only the `the database system is starting up` went to the text file inside the `pg_log` folder.

Comment: Perhaps your database is now corrupted? [Repair Corrupt database postgresql](//stackoverflow.com/q/11030173)

Comment: You should probably also run a `chkdsk {drive:} /f` on all your disk drives